# mysqldump show Table doesn´t exist when doing LOCK TABLES

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, corruption

Our server had power outage and after start some of mysql tables was inaccessible. I tried many things but nothing helped and currently i am at freeze point.

I used command :

```
mysqldump database table > table.sql -u user -p password
```

but result is `Table doesn´t exist when doing LOCK TABLES`. This happend only when table.frm file was in database directory.

When i tried sql command `Show tables` i see my table. Then i droped it and see  error `table doesn´t exists` but *.frm file dissapeared.

Then mysqldump show `Couldn´t find table: table`

If i copy my *.frm file back, then mysqldump show first error.
When i tried used other commands select,drop,analyze,repair i always get error `table doesn´t exists` and cannot try other solution which i can find on net.

Windows server standart
MySQL 5.6.15 Win64

Comment: Are your tables MyISAM or InnoDB?  What is in mysqld.err?

Comment: I can not solve the problem with MySQL tools, so I had to program own code which dig up data from * .ibd files files and import it into old database backups. Hard work and not 100% recovery, but better than nothing.